# Kill a task that is running in Mesos

Tags: mesos

While running some tasks in Mesos, some of my tasks will just freeze. I want to be able to kill these tasks. Is there any way to kill just one task in a Mesos framework? (I don't want to kill the entire framework)

Comment: How do you run these tasks? Frameworks usually have some sort of CLI to manage tasks

Answer (score 2):

http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/executor-http-api/

KILL
The KILL event is sent whenever the scheduler needs to stop execution of a specific task. The executor is required to send a terminal update (e.g., TASK_FINISHED, TASK_KILLED or TASK_FAILED) back to the agent once it has stopped/killed the task. Mesos will mark the task resources as freed once the terminal update is received.

```
{
  "type" : "KILL",
  "kill" : {
    "task_id" : {"value" : "d40f3f3e-bbe3-44af-a230-4cb1eae72f67"}
   }
}
```

Comment: `KILL The KILL event is sent`

Sorry, but I don't think this is correct. You are linking to documentation about events sent by mesos. Not documentation outlining how to make an HTTP call to kill a task. This content is something an event listener receives as a result of a task having been killed in mesos.

Answer (score 0):

from http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/scheduler-http-api/#kill

> #### KILL
>
> Sent by the scheduler to kill a specific task. If the scheduler has a
> custom executor, the kill is forwarded to the executor; it is up to
> the executor to kill the task and send a TASK_KILLED (or TASK_FAILED)
> update. If the task hasn’t yet been delivered to the executor when
> Mesos master or agent receives the kill request, a TASK_KILLED is
> generated and the task launch is not forwarded to the executor. Note
> that if the task belongs to a task group, killing of one task results
> in all tasks in the task group being killed. Mesos releases the
> resources for a task once it receives a terminal update for the task.
> If the task is unknown to the master, a TASK_LOST will be generated.
>
> ```
> KILL Request (JSON):
> POST /api/v1/scheduler  HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: masterhost:5050
> Content-Type: application/json
> Mesos-Stream-Id: 130ae4e3-6b13-4ef4-baa9-9f2e85c3e9af
>
> {
>   "framework_id"    : {"value" : "12220-3440-12532-2345"},
>   "type"            : "KILL",
>   "kill"            : {
>     "task_id"   :  {"value" : "12220-3440-12532-my-task"},
>     "agent_id"  :  {"value" : "12220-3440-12532-S1233"}
>   }
> }
>
> KILL Response:
> HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
> ```